# posting File in angular

Tags: c#, angular, file, .net-core, iformfile

I'm trying to post an uploaded file in angular 5 to c# controller. When I debug my applicaion and post and hit the controller the [FromBody] IFormFile file is always null

Is their a specific {responseType} I need to pass from my angular service?

**Angular Service**

```
public async upload(file: File) {
  try {
    return await this.http.post(this.baseUrl + "api/Blogs/Upload", file).toPromise();
  catch (error) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
  }
}
```

**C# Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/Blogs/Uplaod")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload([FromBody] IFormFile file) {
  // my save logic
}
```

Why is my Post Body always null?

Comment: Do the browser developer tools say the file was sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just pass a file in the body of a post request in Angular. You have to send it as formData

```
uploadFile(file: File) {
  var formData: FormData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', file, file.name);

  var headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Accept', 'application/json');
  var options = { headers: headers };

  const req = new HttpRequest('POST', this.baseUrl + "api/Blogs/Upload", formData, options);
  return this.http.request(req);
}
```

And in your controller, get the file like this

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/Blogs/Upload")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload() {
  var myFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files(0)
  // you can append more than 1 file in angular, but if you know its only ever 1 file, you can just get the `Files(0)` at that index of zero.
  // my save logic
}
```